# Drupal sessions in angular app

Tags: services, sessions

I'm developing an angular application which uses drupal as a backend. When user login to my webapp, they can able to get some data from the drupal backend. Also, I'm maintaining a session for that user in the drupal backend.

I want to get that session values of a user from drupal backend to my angular app. Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: Which version of Drupal? Are you using the Services module to provide end points in Drupal 7? ARe you using core rest in Drupal 8?

Comment: I'm using drupal 7 service module to provide the end points.

Comment: You should edit your question with more details like this.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't use any session data, but I have passed sections of `Drupal.settings` on into the Angular scope when declaring modules. It worked for my case. Here is an example:

```
angular.module('mypackage.name', []).constant('appConfig', Drupal.settings.custom_module.custom_module_config);
```

This lived within the libraries folder (attached to pages by Drupal) for 7.x.

But I am not sure that it really matters what backend you have here, this seems like an Angular question. Here is one that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957450/maintaining-session-through-angular-js